# JList Left Attached and Filled

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlist

```
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(listScroller, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

When i just do this my list being left attached and filled all column size. But when i add more things.

```
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    add(nameLabel, gc);
```

It's being smaller and when i resize it turns unvisible. How i can fit list on left, other thing on right.

**Extra question:** If there is few elements in list, my scroller doesn't show. I wanna see scroller whatever happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you might like to use a single layout manager...

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

gc.gridx = 0;
gc.gridy = 0;
gc.weighty = 1;
gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
add(listScroller, gc);

gc.gridx = 2;
gc.gridy = 0;
gc.weighty = 0;
gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
gc.gridheight = 1;
add(nameLabel, gc);
```

Or

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(listScroller, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(nameLabel);
```

depending on what you want to achieve

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

> Extra question: If there is few elements in list, my scroller doesn't show. I wanna see scroller whatever happens.

You will want to take a look at [`JScrollPane#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(int)) and [`JScrollPane#setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(int))